# Deploying the nodejs express server to the vercel showing the module not found error in function logs

Tags: node.js, web-deployment, serverless, vercel

When I deploy the nodejs application in vercel it shows this error in function logs,
I have already deployed the nodejs application with the same config and file directory this is the first time I am seeing this serverless function error
I want to deploy the nodejs server to vercel because soon Heroku will remove its free tier so please find the issue or if you guys have any recommendations to deploy the nodejs server please let me know

```
[GET] /
15:11:45:53
Function Status:
None
Edge Status:
500
Duration:
94.00 ms
Init Duration:
N/A
Memory Used:
19 MB
ID:
sfo1::7wz8g-1667209305700-0df0949052b6
User Agent:
got (https://github.com/sindresorhus/got)
2022-10-31T09:41:45.636Z    0a0d2c9e-7a8b-46f1-89b7-bf1ea6108d53    ERROR   Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '/var/task/Controllers/Users.controller.js' imported from /var/task/routes/Users.routes.js
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:372:5)
    at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:437:11)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1009:10)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1218:11)
    at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:580:30)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:294:18)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:80:40)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:78:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
RequestId: 0a0d2c9e-7a8b-46f1-89b7-bf1ea6108d53 Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 1
Runtime.ExitError
```

// Users.routes.js

```
import express from "express";

import { get_id, addUser, addFriends, getFriends, getPendingFriends, queryUser, startChat, getChats, getUser, getUserServers, changeUserName, createServers, joinServers } from "../Controllers/Users.controller.js";

const router = express.Router();


// get user id
router.get("/getId", async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const { uid } = req.query;
        const id = await get_id(uid);
        res.status(200).send(id);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        next(error);
    }
});

// add user to the database
router.post("/addUser", addUser);

// search a user through username using get method and query
router.get("/searchUser", queryUser);

// start the chat
router.post("/startChat", startChat);

// get all chats
router.get("/getChats", getChats);

// get logged in user
router.get("/getUserInfo", getUser);

// send and accept the friend request
router.post("/add-friends", addFriends);

// get Accepted Friends
router.get("/getAllFriends", getFriends);

// get Pending Friends
router.get("/getPendingFriends", getPendingFriends)

// create a new server for the user
router.post("/createServer", createServers);

// join a new server for the user
router.post("/joinServer", joinServers);

// getting all servers that users have already joined
router.get("/getallServers", getUserServers);

// change username
router.post("/changeUserName", changeUserName);

export default router;
```

// package.json

```
{
  "name": "user-and-chat-service",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "nodemon index.js",
    "watch": "babel-watch -L src/index.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-watch": "^7.7.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.19.1",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.19.1",
    "@vercel/node": "^2.5.22",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.1.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.2",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "http-errors": "^2.0.0",
    "joi": "^17.6.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.6.2",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "nanoid": "^4.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20"
  }
}
```

// vercel.json

```
{
    "builds": [
        {
            "src": "./index.js",
            "use": "@vercel/node"
        }
    ],
    "routes": [
        {
            "src": "/(.*)",
            "dest": "/index.js"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

replace this for this, vercel.json not working with absolute paths

```
{
"builds": [
    {
        "src": "index.js",
        "use": "@vercel/node"
    }
],
"routes": [
    {
        "src": "/(.*)",
        "dest": "index.js"
    }
]
```

}

Comment: You didn't suggest any new code, it is exactly the same that he mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same issue and I followed the official documentation. I worked well.
[Using Express.js with Vercel](https://vercel.com/guides/using-express-with-vercel)

You should create an api directory and move the main server file to it.